# How to create background music in react native

Tags: react-native

I have seen a lot of tutorials on creating music which can be activated with a button but not on creating background music without a button. Is it possible to create background music which play throughout the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this link for https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MpQ1sVku-D0&t=482s to make background music in the page where it is connected to all the route in my app. If yours is local file, go to https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MpQ1sVku-D0&t=482s and just change the audioclips based on video.(The coding is the same other than it uses url).

[This is part of the code to play without using button that need to modify since video mention button.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n1hrP.png)

Hope this helps!